# How to obtain a list of all available Node.js modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to get some of the NPM functionality into my Node.js programs. In particular, I would like to be able to analyze the available node modules on my system. "Module" here means "module identifier", thus either an identifier like "fd", or a file path; in other words, anything that can be put into a `require()` call and does load a module. 
This question is split into three sub-problems:
1) Get a list of all core modules
2) Get a list of all loaded modules
3) Get a list of all installed and available modules.

Question 1 is answered by zeke's [node-core-module-names](https://github.com/zeke/node-core-module-names) list. Loading another module to find the core modules list is not elegant and it may outdate itself, but it is an option and does work. The (ordered) list is thus `['assert', 'buffer', 'child_process', ..., 'zlib']`.

The 2. question can be answered by a call of `Object.keys(require.cache)`, which returns a list of file paths.

What I cannot elegantly solve by now is the 3. question. There is the shell command `npm ls` which returns a tree graph. But is there anything usable and better?

Thank's for listening!
Tom

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I have found tinkering around and I think this should be valid.

The V8 code has a standard set of bindings which you have seen in Node. They include but are not limited to:

- fs
- path
- http
- etc.

Also, there is a global variable by name of `process`. This exposes process level information and functionality, but *also* lets you get your hands on some V8 code through a function inside of the `process` variable called `bindings`.

The `bindings(...)` functions allows you to interface into exposed C++ libraries created by Node or you can create your own NodeJS modules by following the V8 developer guide (beyond the scope of this answer, read more here).

A [funny little line](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/cf78ce59b3c0a9e7cdcdbd84d71300b04150b6df/src/node.cc#L1802) I saw in the `Node.cc` file included a static check for checking for bindings for a keyword `natives`. This returns, it seems, a list of system level modules that you are looking for, and then some.

So that being said, I went into Node REPL and plugged in two lines (which I am sure can be shortened in a more elegant, expressive manner). Also note that I am pruning out anything starting with an underscore (_) so to preserve private functions or bindings:

`var natives = process.binding('natives');
for (var key in natives) {if (key.indexOf('_') !== 0) {console.log(key);}}`

Comment: This is implementation-dependent, which means that if chakra or gecko are behind it or if this undocumented behavior changes, this will not work.

Comment: Thank you, Tom! What you teach me there is new for me and definitely worth exploring. My problem is solved. Thank you very much!

Comment: Valid point regarding flavor of engine implementation. Glad it provided some insight into some native bindings. :)

Answer (score 1):

`npm list` has [various output options/flags](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls), including `json` and `parseable` (which outputs a list of paths)

Try this:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmd = 'npm ls --json';

exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  var treeObject = JSON.parse(stdout);
});
```

The above requires no external packages but might need more code to work around the buffer limit: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4236

Alternatively `npm` can also be used [programmatically](http://nick-tomlin.com/2015/09/04/programmatically-running-npm-scripts/), perhaps through [global-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-npm):

```
var npm = require('global-npm');
npm.load({}, function (err) {
  npm.commands.list(null, function(err, treeObject) {
    var firstLevelDependenciesArray = Object.keys(treeObject.dependencies);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I go with the `npm ls --parseable`, which solves my problem, and which I oversaw in my research. Thank's a lot, this was a great help!